# Angular scope won't get defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, code-injection

I'm learning Angular and I'm facing a new issue which takes me long to figure out where the problem is

I try to inject

```
konfigurator.factory("ConfigurationService", function($http) {
  return {
    get: function() {
      return $http.get('/api/products');
    }
  };
```

in my controller some json as it follows

```
konfigurator.controller('Configurator', function($scope, products){
          //console.log(products.data); Data is getting logged I have it
          $scope.products  = products.data;        
 });
```

Console shows data as passed but my scope is remaining undefined

```
Error: products is undefined
```

I searched here some issues which are similar and giving a try with

```
 konfigurator.controller('Configurator', ['$scope', function($scope, products) {
          console.log(products.data); // in this case products.data is undefined
          $scope.products = products.data;        
  }]);
```

but in this case I do not see as defined injected data

**Router**

```
konfigurator.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/desktops', {
        templateUrl: '/site/app/partials/products.html',
        controller: 'Configurator',
        resolve: {
            products: function(ConfigurationService) {
                return ConfigurationService.get();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="Configurator">
<h1>Products</h1>
<div ng-repeat="product in products "> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you defined a `products` service? Where is its code?

Comment: As I said I'm quite newbie maybe the issue is where U pointed. I attached my factory. How do declare a service?

Comment: You're trying to inject a service named "products" in your controller. The only service you have defined is named "ConfigurationService". And it doesn't have any `data` field. All it has is a `get()` method.

Comment: fefe,do the phonecat tutorial in AngularJS doc ,there is no excuses for being that lazy and it will save time for everybody.You obviously dont know what you are doing here,this is programming,not magics.

Comment: u know I try to understand things how they work together because I do not want to see things as hocus pocus

Comment: You should have provided the router configuration from the beginning. That's critical information to understand what you are trying to achieve. What is the JSON returned by the backend? What is printed if you add `console.log(products)` in your controller?

Comment: Object { data=[3], status=200, config={...}, more...}  data contains products

Comment: Then how could products.data be undefined? The above log clearly shows that products.data exists and is an array of 3 elements.

Comment: yeah and the log points to $scope.products  = products.data;

Answer (score 0):

Took me a bit till I got it to work,here is a way how to inject data in controller

```
konfigurator.controller('Configurator',['$scope','products', 
      function($scope, products){        
          $scope.products  = products.data;  
          console.log($scope.products);
  }]);
```